# Change icons in Material You bottom navigation bar in active and inactive states

Tags: android, icons, material-design, android-navigation-bar, material-you

Google recently released Material You (M3) for Android.

According to the design guidelines, as stated here: https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-bar/overview, bottom navigation bars' icons have to  be outlined when inactive and filled when active(when there is a suitable outlined version of the icon).

However, in the implementation,  I do not see any way to make the icons outlined when inactive and filled when active.

Do we have to upload 2 versions of the same icon, outlined and filled, and how do we link these 2 icons in our menu resource file?

[image: Menu resource file for bottom navigation]

As seen in the material design documentation, only 1 icon is defined for each menu item.

This results in a filled icon even in an inactive state, as seen below.

[image]

How do we make the icons filled and outlined based on its state? Does this have to be done programmatically or through XML?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to make a another drawable for this where you have to add one selected icon and unselected icon like this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_selected" 
android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_non_selected" 
android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

And than call this here

```
android:icon="your drawable name"
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test this out on my app and accept this answer if it works